# MPEG DASH: frame seeking

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, mp4, mpeg

TL;DR: Is it possible to achieve frame seeking using DASH? How?

I'm using ffmpeg to create non-multiplexed content:

```
ffmpeg -y -an -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline output_video.mp4 -i video.mp4
ffmpeg -y -vn -codec:a libvo_aacenc -ac 1 -ar 44100 output_audio.mp4 -i video.mp4
```

Then I'm using mp4box to create DASH content:

```
mp4box -dash 10000 -frag 1000 -rap -dash-profile live -segment-name mp4-live-$RepresentationID$-$Number$ -out manifest.mpd output_video.mp4 output_audio.mp4
```

Finally I open the generated content with Chrome, using dash.js. Everything works fine except that I can't do frame seek. I keep on adding (1/frame_rate) seconds to the current time but nothing happens, the frame only changes after 10 seconds.

I suppose this has to do with the video's key interval. However, I am able to do frame seek after the ffmpeg part, so I guess I'm missing something in the mp4box command.

Is it possible to achieve frame seeking using DASH or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the mp4box call does not change the bitstream. So converting it to a DASH stream didn't remove any frame seeking ability. I would assume that dash.js is simply not supporting frame-wise seeking. You might want to check your output_video.mp4 with another player (just load the file - it should be playable offline).